# Displaying data after clearing radtextbox telerik

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I am facing an unexpected behavior from radtextbox control of telerik..
Let me show you what I have tried first,

```
function MouseOut(sender, eventArgs) {
            debugger;
            var Invc = new WcfAjaxServices.IInventory();
            var data = null;
            if (sender.get_textBoxValue() != '') {
                if (!isBarCodeInsideGrid(sender)) {
                    Invc.ShowbarCodes(sender.get_textBoxValue(), function (result, context, OnSuccess) {
                        if (result) {
                            debugger;
                            clearBarCode(sender);
                            alert("already exists in database!");
                            eventArgs.
                        }
                    }, function (error, context, OnError) {
                        toastify("error", "ppp", "System Error", "toast-bottom-right", true);
                    }, null);
                } else {
                    clearBarCode(sender);
                    alert("This barcode is already present inside grid");
                }
            } else {
                alert("Insert valid value");

            }
        }
```

Now let me show you the design of the grid here..

[image]

Now, whenever user entered some value it will check

1. If exist in database..
2. If already exist inside grid..

I am able to clear textbox's value for 2nd option i.e If value is already present inside grid,but when it comes to point 1, I am using same code to clear its value but its not working..

Let me show you what I am getting from debugger after clearing text from textbox..

[image]

function that responsible for clearing..

```
function clearBarCode(item) {
            debugger;
            item.set_value("");
            //item.focus();
        }
```

Any idea why this is happening ? Or how to get desired result..

[image]

BarCode001 is still displaying inside grid..